# What can be wrong with shared object (library) produced by Go?

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython

#### Context

I'm trying to build bindings for Python 3 to a program originally written in Go.  Below is what I was able to do so far:

1. Write Go code that exposes functionality to C code.
2. Write glue C code that uses functions exposed by Go code.
3. Write Cython code that calls into C code, which calls into Go code.
4. I can compile my code by hand-crafting the GCC command.

## Problem

The way `setuptools` wants to generate the command, `ld` isn't "able" to find the library.  No amount of hinting doesn't help, and `ld` doesn't produce any parseable output.

The command generated by `setuptools` looks like this:

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pykubectl/lib/bindings.o \
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pykubectl/wrapped.o \
    -lpykubectl.so \
    -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pykubectl/wrapped.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so \
    -L/home/.../pykubectl/pykubectl/lib
```

This fails with: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpykubectl.so`

But, if I do it like this:

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pykubectl/lib/bindings.o \
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/pykubectl/wrapped.o \
    /home/.../pykubectl/pykubectl/lib/libpykubectl.so \
    -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pykubectl/wrapped.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

It does compile.

Here's some info about `libpykubectl.so`:

```
ldd /home/.../pykubectl/pykubectl/lib/libpykubectl.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd7cccd000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f69662d2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6965f0b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e410408000)


file /home/.../pykubectl/pykubectl/lib/libpykubectl.so 
    /home/.../pykubectl/pykubectl/lib/libpykubectl.so: \
    ELF 64-bit LSB shared object,
    x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
    dynamically linked,
    BuildID[sha1]=d4225259207743ceaecda8d90368c13732d0f310,
    not stripped
```

(formatted for readability).

Comment: If you're putting `-lpykubectl.so` that means it's looking for libpykubectl.so.so - you just need `-lpykubectl`

Comment: @ChrisTurner omg, I need more coffee :) Thanks1